# Variable de sustitución PL SQL

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, plsql

Mediante unos array que he creado y unas variables de sustitución que introduzca el usuario podrá poner la nota al alumno no obstante querría saber si puedo poner el nombre y la nota del alumno, el nombre y la nota del alumno... Porque como lo tengo ahora, debo de introducir primero 5 nombres y luego 5 notas.

```
    set serveroutput on;

CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tipo_notas IS VARRAY (3) OF NUMBER (2);
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE tipo_nombre IS VARRAY (3) OF VARCHAR2(10);
DECLARE
    type tipo_notas IS VARRAY (3) OF NUMBER(2);
    type tipo_nombre IS VARRAY (3) OF VARCHAR2(10);
    notas tipo_notas;
    estudiante tipo_nombre;
    total integer;

BEGIN 
    estudiante:=tipo_nombre ('&introduzca_nombre','&introduzca_nombre', '&introduzca_nombre');
    notas:= tipo_notas ('&nota_alumno','&nota_alumno','&nota_alumno');
    total:=notas.count;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('El total de las notas a mostrar son '||total);
    FOR i in 1 .. TOTAL LOOP
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Estudiante: '|| estudiante(i)||' y su calificación en Base de datos es de un '  || notas(i)||'.');
    END LOOP;
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Justo como haces en la segunda parte para mostrar los nombres y las notas, puedes pedirlos con un ciclo que vaya iterando por cada uno de los elementos de los arreglos, en este caso, para asignarles un valor, por ejemplo:

```
--todo lo anterior
begin
  for i in 1..notas.count loop
    estudiante(i) := '&introduzca_nombre';
    notas(i) := '&nota_alumno';
  end loop;
  --sigues con el resto...
```